android 14 execution of binary files raise error=2, No such file or directory
I have several binary files in /data/data/[package_name]/bin/ which are busybox, sshpass ...
Now when i execute the binary files on android <14, the files executed successfully, but when i executes the files in android 14, only busybox is executed successfully but the execution of other files like sshpass raise error=2, No such file or directory, i check, the files are exist and executable.
 
My code:
        String file_path="/data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/sshpass";
        File file = new File(file_path);
        Log.i("my_tag",file.canExecute()+","+file.exists()+"");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(file_path);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("my_tag",e.getMessage());
        }

LogCat:
2024-07-20 10:40:15.221 12350-12350 my_tag                  com.staf621.ki4a                     I  true,true
2024-07-20 10:40:15.262 12350-12350 my_tag                  com.staf621.ki4a                     I  Cannot run program "/data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/sshpass": error=2, No such file or directory

it's weird, on android<14 all binary files are executed without problem, but on android 14, busybox located in the same place as sshpass and  is executed successfully, but for sshpass and other files like iptables,... raise No such file or directory error whereas the files exist and is executable base on ture in logcat. and when i execute command file to detect what kind of file it's the result is: Output: /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/sshpass: ELF shared object, 32-bit LSB 386, dynamic (/system/bin/linker), not stripped and the device cpu arch is x86_64 
Note: all files permission is 777

Make sure the executables don't have the writable flag set for user, group or other in Linux file-system. Also check if the binaries are arm64 - more and more recent Android devices only support arm64 architecture.

i check the executables, they are x86, and the device cpu arch is x86_64. and i set executables permission to chmod 555 sshpass but still not found error. this happens only on android 14. works fine on android <14 like 13,12,..

Android 14 compatibility definitions say that devices with less than 2GB RAM are required to only run 32-bit applications, and devices with 2GB to 4GB are strongly recommended to only run 32-bit applications. It is possible that your device doesn't support 64-bit binaries since Android 14.

all files are x86 not 64 bit still not working. i have realized something weird. my physical phone api level is 33, the app works fine, but a virtual device with api level 33 i created, it not works. the arch on virtual device is x86_64

another question. if a executable don't be compatible with device, it raise not found?
